# Live hardware usage to webpage

Tags: jquery, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to take things like CPU, Memory and Bandwidth utilization from my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) and display these stats live (or as close to live as possible) on a webpage.

I know the graphs can be made using jQuery but how would I feed data that far?

The only idea I have so far is to run the "top" command every few seconds, save it to a .txt file, strip away the unnecessary information and have the jQuery poll the .txt file as data points? Is this even possible? Is there an easier way to do something like this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use jQuery to call a webserver script (like php) on the raspberry which runs these commands and replies them to the client script.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, worth mentioning that there are a few off-the-shelf tools that deliver this graphing functionality. I've had good experiences with a software called munin. But it may be too slow for you by default (updates every 5min). Not sure if you can speed that up.

You can do it as you suggest with `top` output written to a file and parsed, or you can call `top` from a page handler of a small PHP/Python webapp, parse its output and serve it on demand as JSON.

Writing something to get the metrics using a library and serve the result as JSON on demand may be simpler than parsing `top` output though.

In python I've done something like this with [Psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil) and [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). There must be similar libraries if you prefer another language.

Example snippet that serves cpu usage stats below. You can use the same program to serve the HTML page that contains HTML + javascript to render graphs. Uses the Flask built-in webserver so standalone. Downside is that you need to install the two dependencies on the Pi.

```
import time

import psutil
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/stats/cpu.json")
def stats_cpu():
    cpu_time_pct = psutil.cpu_times_percent()
    d = {
        'time': time.time(),
        'user': cpu_time_pct.user,
        'system': cpu_time_pct.system,
        'idle': cpu_time_pct.idle,
    }
    # flask.jsonify returns the dict as json with the
    # proper content-type header
    return flask.jsonify(**d)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

To get it running, save into a file (say example.py) and in the shell:

```
$ apt-get install python-pip
$ pip install flask psutil
$ python example.py
```

Then visit `localhost:5000/stats/cpu.json`. You can fetch this periodically with jquery and update your graphs. The response should look something like:

```
{
  "idle": 89.1, 
  "system": 3.9, 
  "time": 1457475545.336526, 
  "user": 6.9
}
```